# rewrite website architecture using a nosql database

Tags: nosql

i want to rewrite an existing website, for a client, that has 100000+ visitors a day and i am considering using Cassandra db, Couch Db or Mongo Db instead of using Mysql and couple it  with Solr.

what i want to ask is if it is a good idea to switch to nosql for a website that sits on a single server(would not use for now multiple nodes)?

what problems that may arise on the long term. I am a little afraid of using nosql because these db`s are relatively young. But considering the speed gain for queries makes it really attractive.

i am using php as the backend programming language.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the platforms you mention are very young compared to SQL, they have now been around long enough that they are somewhat mature and you don't risk much by using them instead of SQL if they fit what you are trying to do.

However, in this case it may be better to stick with SQL - you already have all the code working well with SQL, and you can get most of the performance improvements you need by adding a search engine or cache component rather than rewriting the entire system.

If the rewrite is something you were planning to do anyway, you can use any datastore you want - just pick the one where the standard datamodel is closest to your data and the queries you need to support.

Comment: i think i am going to look into solandra:)

i need to rewrite the website because it has a lot of problems/bugs & security issue which makes it hard to maintain

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the most difficult thing will be to transform your data model for nosql DB. There will be no `JOIN`, and 'workarounds' for joins are not that straightforward in nosql databases.

Also, performance is not guaranteed out of the box, you will have to work hard to achieve it. Nosql databases have relaxed constraints on your data, which in turn provides developers with more options on how to work with that data; which in turn enables higher-performance solutions.

Many nosql DBs are still quite young. They may be used in many successful projects, but yet, in general they are not as reliable as popular relational DBs. Of course, it is unlikely for them to fail in a big way, but the likelihood of small bugs here and there is higher.

Perhaps the most well known failure associated with nosql was [foursquare's mongodb outage](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/10/4square_mongodb_outage). But it doesn't look that big of a deal to me.